# $scope.watch doesn't work in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

$scope.watch doesn't work in ionic framework

I was designing some fliter in ionic..It won't work ..the same code is working properly on blank test app as well as angularjs...

My html

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-royal">
  <div class="h1 title">Hotel search</div>
</div>
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>

        <h4 style="margin-top:100px;color:#116262;margin-left:10px;font-weight:bold"><i class="icon ion-edit"></i> Request Form</h4>
        <div class="list" style="margin-top:15px;">

            <label class="item item-input item-select">
              <div class="input-label" style="font-weight:bold">
                City
              </div>
              <select ng-model="formData.city">
                <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label" style="font-weight:bold">CheckIn</span>
                <input type="date" ng-model="formData.checkIn"  value="{{formData.checkIn |  date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label" style="font-weight:bold">checkOut</span>
                <input type="date" ng-model="formData.checkOut"  value="{{formData.checkOut |  date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
              <div class="input-label" style="font-weight:bold">
                Rooms
              </div>
              <select ng-model="formData.room">
                <option value="1" ng-selected="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
              <div class="input-label" style="font-weight:bold">
                Adults
              </div>
              <select ng-model="formData.adult">
                <option value="1" ng-selected="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <div class="row center" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="button button-outline button-block button-royal" ng-click="submit(formData)" style="text-align:center;">
                      Search
                </button>
            </div>
            {{formData}}
            <input type="text" ng-model="useStars"/>
            {{fooChanges}}
        </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My controller is

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope,$state) {

    $scope.formData ={};
    $scope.formData.checkIn = new Date();
    $scope.formData.checkOut= new Date();
    $scope.formData.checkOut.setDate($scope.formData.checkOut.getDate() + 1);
    $scope.formData.room = 1;
    $scope.formData.city = 'Chennai';
    $scope.formData.adult = 1;
    $scope.useStars = 'balakumaran';
    $scope.fooChanges = 1;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            useStars : $scope.useStars,
        }
    },function (value) {
        alert('');
    },true);

    $scope.submit = function(formData){
      $state.go('app.search',{formData:formData});
    }

})
```

what's problem on above code ?? ..I tried lot of times..it won't wrk..if have any alternative idea's??

Comment: You can rewrite your watch to :  $scope.$watch('useStars',function (value) {
        alert('');
    },true);

Comment: i also try this ..it won't work..

Comment: what about <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.useStars"/> ? or <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.$parent.useStars"/> (just in case).

Comment: Thank You... @Walfrat It's working by using $parent...Thank u very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment the problem was resolved doing the following :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.useStars"/>
```

However the best way to never have this problem : always use an intermdediary object like `$scope.data.userStarts`. So you won't ever need the `$parent` trick, this is called dot notation in Angular and is due to limit of javascript inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In your button you are passing the **formData** as parameter

```
<button class="button button-outline button-block button-royal" ng-click="submit(formData)" style="text-align:center;">
                      Search
                </button>
```

in your controller there is not formData parameter is refereed except in your search button in the same way you should pass the `useStars` .

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
     formData ={};
    formData.checkIn = new Date();
    formData.checkOut= new Date();
    formData.checkOut.setDate($scope.formData.checkOut.getDate() + 1);
    formData.room = 1;
    formData.city = 'Chennai';
    formData.adult = 1;
    $scope.useStars = 'balakumaran';
    $scope.fooChanges = 1;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            useStars : $scope.useStars,
             $state.go('app.search',{formData:formData});
        }
    },function (value) {
        alert('');
    },true);

   $scope.submit = function(formData){
      $state.go('app.search',{formData:formData});
    }
});
```

Here you don't need $scope before form angularjs itself create a scope variable if some event occurs.

but there is no event is occurring so there is no way for PlaylistCtrl can understand $scope.formData so try to make an event to be appeare or try to understand the [$scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

so that will help for two way databinding